# OpenCV Real-time screen capture put rectangle around items in ROI Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

Hi I am having trouble figuring out, how to put little rectangles around the objects that appear in the my live screen captures ROI.

With OpenCV I have seen examples for template matching on static images, and cascades on live video from webcams, I have also seen video examples that show lines for cars to drive in lanes.

I am looking basic example that highlights rectangles around the objects in my ROI, with eventually the chance to use pyautogui to click these items.

Below is my code so far.

```
#!python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
#import time


# define the region of interest function
def roi(img, vertices):
    mask = np.zeros_like(img)
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, vertices, 255)
    masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)
    return masked


# how the image is going to be processed
def process_img(original_image):

    # convert it to grey
    processed_img = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # add thresholding
    processed_img = cv2.Canny(processed_img, threshold1=150, threshold2=200)
    # add blur
    processed_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(processed_img, (3, 3), 0)

    # Create a Region of Interest (ROI) 
    vertices = np.array([[200, 440], [200, 250], [200, 250], [450, 250], [450, 250], [450, 440]], np.int32)
    processed_img = roi(processed_img, [vertices])
    return processed_img


def main():
    #last_time = time.time()
    while True:
        screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(40, 420, 720, 1000)))
        new_screen = process_img(screen)
        #print('Loop took {} seconds'.format(time.time()-last_time))
        #last_time = time.time()
        cv2.imshow('game window', new_screen)
        #cv2.imshow('window2', cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):  # press q to escape.
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Is someone could fill in the gaps, I feel I am close but not quite there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem with your current code ?

Comment: Hi, It doesn't select items in the ROI with rectangles around them I am clearly missing code to select objects in the ROI with rectangles around them ...

Comment: You can start by making rectangles  around detected faces in webcam,detecting eyes etc.If you want I can help you with that.

Comment: Hi I have already achieved that to an extent however i had difficulty transitioning the code from the webcam examples to the live screen recording.